# How to Hide Menu Items Based on Role in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to hide an Item from the Menu Items if a user is not in the Admin role.  Here is the code that i am using in the code behind in my site master but the code is not hiding the Admin page in which i am trying to hide it.  Here is the HTML markup for the master page:

```
 <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Authors.aspx" Text="Admin" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Users/KCA_Summary.aspx" Text="KCA Summary" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Users/Details.aspx" Text="KCA Details" />

                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Not Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") Then
            Dim menuItems As MenuItemCollection = NavigationMenu.Items
            Dim adminItem As New MenuItem()
            For Each menuItem As MenuItem In menuItems
                If menuItem.Text = "Admin" Then
                    adminItem = menuItem
                End If
            Next
            menuItems.Remove(adminItem)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you're in the Admin role :). That code works for me.

Comment: i have removed myself from the Admin role to test it but still does not work.

Comment: If you are using Asp.net Membership, you can use the LoginView Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use a [SiteMapProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.aspx) configured with `SecurityTrimmingEnabled` = true.

The linked MSDN article references a lot of "How To" articles that will help you get started.